# The Legend of the matplotlib graph is not showing in plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to put the legend in my precision-recall curve graph but its not showing in the plot. there is one log output which is "No handles with labels found to put in legend." I am unable to get it why its not working help please .. already I saw other related threads but not getting help that's why I posted here

```
precision1, recall1, thresholds1 = precision_recall_curve(y_true1, y_score1)
plt.ylabel('Precision')
plt.xlabel('Recall')
plt.legend(loc="upper right")
plt.plot(recall1, precision1, label = "Model")
```

Comment: In your sequence you're plotting the legend before any curve exists in the plot. Try switching the last 2 lines around.

Answer (score 1):

The `plt.legend(loc="upper right")` command must be placed after the `plt.plot` command!